# How to remove a single class when iterating over a node list in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to remove one of two classes BUT leave any other class(es) in place.

For example, I start with a node like this:

```
<td class="aaa ddd">
```

I want to remove only `aaa`. I also want to use a selector that selects many nodes at once.

For example:

```
dojo.query('#foo td').removeClass(['aaa','bbb']);
```

The above piece of code removes all classes in the TD. I just want to remove 'aaa' or 'bbb'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have posted seems to work to me.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
<script>
dojo.addOnLoad(function()
{
    dojo.query('#foo td').removeClass(['aaa', 'bbb']);
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.aaa
{
    color: red;
}

.bbb
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.ccc
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.ddd
{
    background-color: gray;
}
</style>
<table id="foo">
    <tr>
        <td class="aaa bbb ccc ddd">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="aaa bbb ccc">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="aaa bbb ccc ddd">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="aaa bbb ccc">D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="aaa bbb ccc ddd">E</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```